# Find number of pairs of digits in a number N that add up to 10

Tags: recursion

23 has no pairs since 2 + 3 != 10

73 has 1 pair since 7 + 3 = 10

783436 has 3 pairs since 7 + 3, 7 + 3, 6 + 4 = 10

I'm trying to use recursion to solve this. Here are my base cases:

```
  if n < 10:
        return 0
  if n >= 10 and n <= 99:
        if n % 10 + n // 10 == 10:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

But the recursive step is eluding me.

Comment: You mean 2 + 3 = 5 != 10

Comment: 4 + 3 + 3 is not a pair, it is a triplet.

Comment: Why use recursion and complicate things when it can be done using a loop?

Comment: @hrv - It's an assignment.

Comment: Come up with a solution using a loop, then figure out how to implement the loop with recursion.

Comment: In the example you gave: `783436` you counted twice `7+3` so it's either a mistake or you meant finding all the **ordered** pairs

Comment: @JamesGold From the looks of things, do you want a solution in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a wonderful solution if you're using recursion in Python:

```
def ten_maker(some_number=str):

    # Base case
    if len(some_number) == 1:
        return

    # Comparing first item to the rest to see if it adds up to 10
    for var in some_number[1:]:
        if int(some_number[0]) + int(var) == 10:
            print(some_number[0], var)

    # Doing the same with the rest, and slowly finishing the string
    return ten_maker(some_number[1:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ten_maker("783436")
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice one of the solutions gives an ***O(n<sup>2</sup>)*** complexity solution. You can actually write an algorithm which runs in ***O(n)***. Here is how it's done:

**(1)** Run through the digits and count up all of the 1's, 2's, ... 9's.

```
int[] A = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
String numStr = "783436";
for(char c: numStr.toCharArray())
    A[c - '0'] += 1;
```

**(2)** Only certain pairs add to give you 10, {1,9}, {2,8}, {3,7}, {4,6}, {5,5}. Using this information sum up the pairs:

```
int pairs = A[1]*A[9] + A[2]*A[8] + A[3]*A[7] + A[4]*A[6] + A[5]*A[5];
```

*(NOTE: you multiply counts because, as stated in the question, pairs don't have to be unique)*

---

As an example take 783436 (note: this isn't actual code, I'm just trying to illustrate):

```
//The counts for digits 1 - 9
A = {0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}

pairs = 0*0 + 0*1 + 2*1 + 1*1 + 0*0 = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the fact that you're counting 7+3 twice (since 3 appears twice in the sequence of digits), then you can do as follows (written in Java):

```
// a helper function that takes a number and returns an array of digits
static int[] numberToDigits(int number){
    char[] charNums = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray();
    int[] digits = new int[charNums.length];
    for(int i=0; i<charNums.length; i++){
        digits[i] = charNums[i]-48; // convert the char to int value
    }
    return digits;
}

// here's the algorithm that counts the pairs
static int count(int number){
    int[] digits = numberToDigits(number);
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<digits.length; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<digits.length; j++){
            if(digits[i]+digits[j] == 10){
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

public static void main(String...args){
    int tens = count(783436);
    System.out.println("tens = " + tens);
}
```

**OUTPUT**
tens = 3

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution **without recrussion**

[code at online compiler](http://ideone.com/F0VYvT)

---

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    // add user input
    int SUM = 10;
    // add user input
    String numStr = "783436";

    int length = numStr.length();

    int numArray[] = new int[length];
    int numArrayNeed[] = new int[length];

    int temp=Integer.parseInt(numStr);
    int i=0;

    do
    {

        numArray[i] = temp % 10;
        temp = temp /10;

        numArrayNeed[i] = SUM - numArray[i];

        i++;

    }while(temp>0);

    for(int j=0;j<length;j++)
    {
        if(numStr.contains( String.valueOf(numArrayNeed[j]) ))
        {
            System.out.println(": " + numArrayNeed[j] + " & " + (10-numArrayNeed[j]) );
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You can add if-case optimization of output as per need . If feel this maybe more memory efficient than extensive looping

Comment: for unique values you can simply add the greatest number of a pair (in 7&3 add 7 to list) and do needed formatting at output ( 7 & (10-7) )

Answer (score 0):

Use below code which is of order n(optimum).

Take a global variable which will hold the occurrence of 0-9

```
private int[] countOfDigits = new int[10];
```

Use below method which will return the total number of pairs available.

```
int countPair(int num) {
    while (num > 0) {
        countOfDigits[num % 10]++;
        num /= 10;
    }

    return ((countOfDigits[1] * countOfDigits[9])
            + (countOfDigits[2] * countOfDigits[8])
            + (countOfDigits[3] * countOfDigits[7])
            + (countOfDigits[4] * countOfDigits[6]) + (countOfDigits[5]
        * (countOfDigits[5] - 1) / 2));
    }
```